# Why is it reading number of letters instead of words?

Tags: java

I have to write a program that reads the input from a text file!

```
Beware the Jabberwock, my son, 
the jaws that bite, the claws that catch, 
Beware the JubJub bird and shun 
the frumious bandersnatch.
```

I should print the number of lines, the longest line, the number of tokens on each line and the length of the longest token on each line.

I'm trying to figure out why is it that im my code is reading the number of letter     instead of the number of words!

```
Line 1 has 5 tokens (longest = 11) 
Line 2 has 8 tokens (longest = 6) 
Line 3 has 6 tokens (longest = 6) 
Line 4 has 3 tokens (longest = 13) 
Longest line : the jaws that bite, the claws that catch,
```

This should be my output.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class InputStats{
    public static void main (String [] args )
            throws FileNotFoundException{

        Scanner console = new Scanner ( System.in);
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Please enter  a name of a file " );
        String name = console.nextLine();
        Scanner input = new Scanner ( new File (name));
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            inputStats(new Scanner(line));
        }
    }//end of amin

    public static void inputStats (Scanner input)
            throws FileNotFoundException{
        int numLines=0;
        int numwords=0;
        int Longest=0;
        String maxLine = "";

        while (input.hasNextLine()){
            String next = input.nextLine();

            numwords += next.length();
            numLines++;
        }//end of while

        System.out.print("Line " + numLines + " has ");
        System.out.print(numwords + "tokens " );
        System.out.println("(longest = " + Longest + ")");
    }//end of method
}// end of class
```

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the length of each line to the `numwords` counter variable instead of the number of words per line. Instead of

```
numwords += next.length();
```

you could split based on whitespace

```
numwords += nextLine.split("\\s+").length;
```

Comment: If im trying to count the letter of only one word instead of all the line how would i change this to work ..  if (next.length() > maxLine.length()) {
maxLine = next;  cus with this is giving me the number of letter but in the line

Comment: its not clear what you mean. I suggest posting another question with that code explaining what isnt working :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are looking for, something like this should work,

```
public static void inputStats(Scanner input)
      throws FileNotFoundException {
  int numLines = 0;
  int numwords = 0;
  String longest = "";
  String maxLine = "";

  while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String nextLine = input.nextLine();
    nextLine = (nextLine != null) ? nextLine
        .trim() : "";
    if (nextLine.length() > maxLine.length()) {
      maxLine = nextLine;
    }
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(
        nextLine);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
      String token = st.nextToken();
      token = (token != null) ? token.trim() : "";
      if (token.length() == 0) {
        continue;
      }
      numwords++;
      if (token.length() > longest.length()) {
        longest = token;
      }
    }
    numLines++;
  }// end of while
  System.out.print("Line " + numLines + " has ");
  System.out.print(numwords + "tokens ");
  System.out.println("(longest = " //
      + longest + ")");
}// end of method
```